# How to serialize an object to XML that can be stored SQL database field of type XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml-serialization

I have a c# web MVC application.
I wish to serialize my model object to an XML to be stored in a SQL database field of type XML?

I was able to serialize to a file using:

```
   var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(car));

   var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\car.xml");

   Writer.Serialize(file, car);

   file.Close();
```

How can I modify this code to serialize to type XML of which I can then store into my SQL table and field XML type

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringWriter` with `XmlWriter` to produce the xml string then save to your database

```
string xmlResult = string.Empty;
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(car));
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, car);
    }
    xmlResult = stringWriter.ToString();
}

// save xmlResult to DB
```